# boost::bind & boost::function pointers to overloaded or templated member functions

Tags: c++, templates, boost, pointer-to-member

I have a callback mechanism, the classes involved are:

```
class App
{
    void onEvent(const MyEvent& event);
    void onEvent(const MyOtherEvent& event);

    Connector connect;
}

class Connector
{  
   template <class T> void Subscribe(boost::function <void (const T&)> callback);
}

App::App()
{
    connect.Subscribe<MyEvent>(&App::OnEvent<MyEvent>);
}
```

First off this code doesn't compile, it's an illustration.

The use of templates complicates my example, but I left them in because its affecting my problem. It seems certain to me that my subscribe needs to be templated because the Connector class doesn't know how many event types it handles. When I try to create a:

```
boost::function f = &App::OnEvent,
```

I tried creating OnEvent as a template function, with specializations, but it seems that the compiler is treating my OnEvent functions as overloads rather than template specializations, or else I get the template specialization not in namespace error if I try to explicitly declare it as

```
template <> OnEvent(const MyEvent& e) ...
```

I can get the following to compile:

```
boost::function <void (App*, const MyEvent&)> f = &App::OnEvent;
f(this, e);
```

That compiles, runs, and works.

```
boost::function<void (const MyEvent&)> g = boost::bind(&App::OnEvent, this);
```

does not. I think its because I'm not correctly specifying the address of an overloaded function.

Having now explained all this to the teddy bear - I think that my question is "How do I correctly create a function pointer to an overloaded or templated member function and bind the this pointer to it?"

Comment: I googled this having the exact same problem with event generation, what are the odds!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you need to disambiguate the address of the overloaded function.  You can do this by explicitly casting the function pointer to the one with the correct parameters.

```
boost::bind( static_cast<void (App::*)( MyEvent& )>(&App::OnEvent) , this, _1);
```

[Similar problem + solution on gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/371209-boostbind-on-overloaded-methods/)

Comment: It's a shame you can only have one accepted answer, but this was the piece I was missing. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I'm glad that I need this answer again now that I have enough reputation to up-vote it!

Answer (score 4):

You are going to want to do

```
boost::function<void (const MyEvent&)> g = boost::bind(&App::OnEvent, this, _1);
```

You should be able to do g(event); with that

I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but that should solve one of your problems for now.

Comment: I've tried, and I think that is the proper use of bind, the problem is "no matching function call to bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, App* const, boost::arg<1>&).  I've also tried to do this with templated OnEvent in the App class, in order to get around this by providing a specialization on argument type for the events I wish to subscribe, and explicitly specifying the template parameter. But I still haven't figured  that one out yet.

Comment: That code will make g(event) work, but it will not exactly work with templates like I think you want.
If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do you might be better off forgetting that template and use an event interface declaration instead.  I would be interested to see how boost::function would work with a templated function definition, but I do not think that is possible.
You might want to check out Boost::Fusion and the Interpreter example in the lib directory.  It is the most advanced Boost::function implementer I know of. libs/function_types/example/interpreter.hpp

Comment: I removed the templates from the OnEvent side (subscribe is still templated), and it works for one event. But as soon as I overload OnEvent, it can no longer deduce which one. I can see why, as the function pointer knows its type, but boost::bind does not.